# Send an email containing a PDF where data is pulled from google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Get data from google spreadsheet
2. put that data in a google docs template
3. convert template into pdf
4. Send to recipient

I can't seem to find error but it might just also be because I'm still very new at scripting as I can't receive the email despite not encountering any errors.

Photo #1 is the table from the spreadsheets where by typing 'yes' will trigger numbers 1-4 to execute. This is the [doc template](http://surl.li/fiwps).

[Photo #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyQ0c.png)

```
function populateDocTemplate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Quotation');
  const data = sheet.getRange('A1:K1').getValues()[0];
  const placeholders = {
    date: '{{date}}',
    requesterName: '{{requesterName}}',
    subject: '{{subject}}',
    company: '{{company}}',
    companyAddress: '{{companyAddress}}',
    issue: '{{issue}}',
    workScope: '{{workScope}}',
    totalJobAMT: '{{totalJobAMT}}',
    completionDays: '{{completionDays}}'
  };
  const triggerValue = sheet.getRange('L1').getValue();
  
  if (triggerValue.toLowerCase() !== 'yes') {
    return;
  }

  const templateDoc = DocumentApp.openById('1dTXKd__KvcSD76vrJWo9k71K7Kg1s5Cvph33NAVBD2w');
  const body = templateDoc.getBody();

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(placeholders)) {
    body.replaceText(value, data[key]);
  }

  const pdfBlob = templateDoc.getAs('application/pdf').setName(`${data.company} Quotation.pdf`);
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1CHYdOleeKTxyEACZMF9nB7iLXlKDEnVh');
  const file = folder.createFile(pdfBlob);

  const recipient = sheet.getRange('L1').getValue();
  const subject = 'Populated Google Doc';
  const emailBody = '<p>Hello, </p><br/><br/><p> Please see attached quotation.</p><br/><br/><p>Regards,</p><p>Ramon Caballero</p>';

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipient,
    subject: subject,
    body: emailBody,
    htmlBody: emailBody,
    attachments: [pdfBlob]
  });
}
```

Comment: About `Photo #1 is the table from the spreadsheets where by typing 'yes' will trigger numbers 1-4 to execute.` and your sample image, if the sheet of your sample image is `Quotation`, when I saw your sample image, the cell "L1" is "Send Question?". In your situation, you change this cell to `yes`? Because, in your script, from `const triggerValue = sheet.getRange('L1').getValue();`, if the cell "L1" is not `yes`, `triggerValue.toLowerCase() !== 'yes'` is always true. By this, the script is stopped this if statement. I'm worried about this. How about this?

Comment: Welcome. The reason that you are not getting/sending any emails is because of this line: `const recipient = sheet.getRange('L1').getValue();` - You need to be targeting Cell C2 or below. In addition, your data range ('A1:K1') is merely the header row; surely you need to be accessing the data rows. If you need further help, please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that allows us to reproduce the problem.